# Looping wc through multiple folders counting the words for each text file

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a structure where one folder contains many subfolders that each have some .txt documents in it. I'm looking for a way to find the average text lengths (in words). Therefore I want to count the words in each .txt file using wc.

I've tried so far: `ls */*.txt | wc -w` (which sadly outputs only a single number).

My other attempt was using `for docs in /home/.../myfolder/*.txt do wc -w docs;`

Which just cancels itself after some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make use of `find` command to execute `wc` recursively:

```
find -type f -name "*.txt" -exec wc -w {} \;
```

Alternatively, via [recursive glob](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49917/85039) in `bash`:

```
shopt -s globstar
wc -w **/*.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! This works excellent, is there a way to store this output in its own textfile? (Possibilty without printing the file name? Just a convenience not a requirement whatsoever). The second suggestion is much faster for btw.

Comment: @Mangobae   Yeah, it's possible. Probably easiest would be `wc -w **/*.txt | cut -f 2 > word_counts`. Also beware that if you do `wc -w **/*.txt | cut -f 2 > word_counts.txt` , the `word_counts.txt` will be included in the glob, since redirections are performed first, then globs, IIRC.  There's other ways,too, but that's simplest probably.